# Search A / B or "A / B" or A/B in Alfresco 4.2d have issues

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have a custom model in which I have a property having following constraint :

```
<constraint name="abc:customList" type="LIST">
       <title>Custom List</title>
         <parameter name="allowedValues">
            <list>
              <value></value>
               <value>ABC</value>
               <value>A / B</value>
               <value>A/B</value>
             </list>
         </parameter>
         <parameter name="caseSensitive"><value>true</value></parameter>
      </constraint>
```

and I have created various documents having different value of above property.

I have created a custom search form on which there are some drop-down list. when I search A / B, It gives no result but If I searched A/B it works.
Also when I searched "A / B" it also work.

This search functionality was working fine in Alfresco 4.2.c for all cases.

I am not able to identify why this is not working in Alfresco 4.2.d

Comment: can you post some sample queries that you create after the user selects the A / B and the "A / B" options? Are you using Solr or Lucene to index the repository?

Comment: are you sure you didn't forgot the atomic indexing property on the field?

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco Search has still some "unexpected" behavior. Alfresco makes changes from version to version but unfortunately there is no documentation about these changes. We should create a page in the Wiki like "discovered search indexing and search behavior by version".
The issue you describe looks pretty much like tokenizing which splits your property. This is the default but in most cases not what you want. Have you defined tokenizing in your model? Please change or add

```
<tokenised>false</tokenised>
```

in your model and recreate the index.

Comment: Thanks for reply ! I have tried by defining tokenizing in model and recreate the index but still it was not working